# Macbook pro 2015 15inch a1398 trackpad not clicking after battery replacement

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, trackpad, magic-trackpad

Today I switched out batteries on my Macbook Pro 2015 15 inch A1398. After I was done I noticed my trackpad doesn't give me feedback or lets me click/select text.

My searches have so far not found anything similar, so that's why I'm reaching out.

I performed an SMC reset, ran diagnostics, with no result.
did the other things nothing is working

So all I'd like to know what can the problem be, and how can I solve it?

-I have verified that the trackpad is connected.

-I am using the MACOS 12.6

-Yes i also checked the settings for trackpad and feedback but nothing changed there

Comment: Please update your post with the version of macOS you are using. Also, have you checked `System Preferences | Trackpad | Point & Click | Force Click and Haptic Feedback (tick)` ? If that's the issue, please update your answer with that detail before someone else comes along and marks it as 'Not an answer'. Then you can also mark your answer as accepted. Oh, and welcome to Ask Different.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it sounds like you've damaged either your trackpad cable or the trackpad itself during the battery removal/installation process. You're going to want to try replacing the cable first as it is very easily accessible on your model (the cable running over the middle of your battery) & if that doesn't make a difference, replace the trackpad itself which you will need a T5 screwdriver for. Hope this helps.